# Express 3.0 upgrade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Will some of the features in express 2 get deprecated in express 3?

I'm creating a pretty big project using express and should i stick to express 2 or will i run into problems later if i want to upgrade to express 3?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562/177538)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best to refer to the migration guide [Migrating from 2.x to 3.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) to find the answers specific to your intended application.